# RewriteRule on Debian to shorten an URL

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, debian

I'm trying to write a `RewriteRule` to shorten the [Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/) URL like this:

```
http://10.0.11.11:8089/monitorix-cgi/monitorix.cgi?mode=multihost.all&graph=all&when=1day&color=black
```

to like: `http://10.0.11.11:8089/mon/all`

So, I added this to the */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* (on Debian wheezy) at the end:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/?mon/all/?$ monitorix-cgi/monitorix.cgi?mode=multihost.all&graph=all&when=1day&color=black [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it's not working. I get: `The requested URL /mon/all was not found on this server.` I found a couple of posts here on similar matter but nothing really wo0rking for me. Any idea what's am I doing wrong? Is it the port-number in the URL that creating the actual problem Cheers!!

---

***Updated*** with `RewriteLog` (as suggested by @williamt):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
  RewriteLogLevel 9
  RewriteRule ^/mon/all/?$ http://10.0.11.11:8089/monitorix-cgi/monitorix.cgi?mode=multihost.all&graph=all&when=1day&color=black [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the full domain name in the substitution:

```
RewriteRule ^/mon/all/?$ http://10.0.11.11:8089/monitorix-cgi/monitorix.cgi?mode=multihost.all&graph=all&when=1day&color=black [NC,L]
```

(I've tested this).

For the benefit of others reading this, the `/?$` in the pattern means you match either `/mon/all` or `/mon/all/` but nothing afterwards; the question mark makes the preceding token - the closing forward-slash - optional, the $ indicates the end of the string.

**Tip:** Use [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) to see exactly what's happening when you're testing rewrite rules (remember to turn it off afterwards) - in particular look for 'matched' and 'not-matched' at the end of the line.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to test it by myself yet but it's surprising. I've been through a number of docs on Apache website and none of them actually says about using full domainname. Can you please explain how does this substitution actually work?

Comment: @MacUsers Good point.. I have used a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) to fix odd problems in the past, but it should be OK for this; in fact I've just created a test PHP script and used '/test.php?mode=multihost...' for the substitute URL and I can pass the whole query string through without issue.  Are you sure it's not just because you're missing a / before 'monitorix.cgi' (if I remove that, I get a 400 bad request error, different to you). Failing that, enable rewritelog & post results. (I'll update my answer if any of this works for you...)

Comment: thanks williamt! Some reason, it still doesn't work for me - I get the same error. Any thing you can think of that I'm missing? I get `404 Not found` error. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers If you enable the rewritelog and paste an example, that'll make it simpler to debug at which stage it's failing.

Comment: I already enabled the logging but noting gets written in the log. I've updated my original posting: this is what it looks like now. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers Is the rewrite module definitely loaded? The output of `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -M` should include `rewrite_module` and regardless of whether a rule is correct/being followed you should see a load of output in rewrite.log for every request.

Comment: I can see `rewrite_module (shared)` is listed there and I still don't get anything logged in the `rewrite.log` file. I'm running out of ideas. Cheers!!